# How do I determine why the temp files are not being created?

Tags: swift, xcode, admob

**Update:** While a root cause has not been determined for these errors. I have been able to fix my issues via reimporting and reinstalling the Google AdMob Manual SDK all together.

*New to this whole Stackoverflow, not sure if I should make that as the answer?*

I'm attempting to install the Google AdMob module into my SwiftUI iOS application using the Manual SDK method located on their documentation page. The project throws no errors until I build the project, at that time it tells me "Build Succeeded" then tells me the below error. When I navigate to the path, I can get to the following directory however, there is no further file there...

```
/Users/PROFILE/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEVICE_UUID/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging
```

I have ensure that the Info.plist is in the directory. I have also verified that the path is proper via the Build Settings.

```
Please try again later.

Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/PROFILE/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEVICE_UUID/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.z14Qmt/extracted/HealthCalc.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework; 

Extra info about "/Users/PROFILE/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEVICE_UUID/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.z14Qmt/extracted/HealthCalc.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist": 

Couldn't stat /Users/PROFILE/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEVICE_UUID/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.z14Qmt/extracted/HealthCalc.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
```

Comment: In answer to your meta question: It is totally legal and encouraged to answer your own question! Do _not_ give the answer in the question. Give it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @matt, I wasn't sure as I am not truly sure of the answer aside from the fact I took a few steps back and redid everything. I can mark that as the answer for now with that caveat.

Answer (score 0):

While a root cause has not been determined for these errors. I have been able to fix my issues via reimporting and reinstalling the Google AdMob Manual SDK all together.

In doing so I followed the [Manual SDK Instructions](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start), particularly I believe the root issue was some funky indentation or mishap in the Info.plist. That being said, if you run into a similar issue, I urge you to take a step back. Start a fresh blank project and attempt to implement the Google AdMob procedures in the blank project. This will eliminate the concern that your current code is causing any conflicts. Once completed and you have it working, mimic the steps within your core project.